# Is there a way to get arrows() in R to plot to plot 'T' shaped arrow heads rather than reverse arrow?

Tags: r, graphics, arrows

I would like to use the `arrows` function in R to plot different shaped arrow heads onto a network graph (I'm using NetworkD3 and iGraph which both use the `arrows` function). This works great at the moment but I would like some to be normal triangular arrow heads and others to be 'T' shaped arrow heads. The `arrows` function says:

```
arrows(x0, y0, x1 = x0, y1 = y0, length = 0.25, angle = 30,
       code = 2, col = par("fg"), lty = par("lty"),
       lwd = par("lwd"), …)
```

**code** = integer code, determining *kind* of arrows to be drawn.
If `code = 1` an arrowhead is drawn at `(x0[i], y0[i])` and if `code = 2` an arrowhead is drawn at `(x1[i], y1[i])`. If `code = 3` a head is drawn at both ends of the arrow. Unless `length = 0`, when no head is drawn.

Currently I'm using `code` to determine what direction the arrows are drawn in, all well and good, but I was wondering if it was possible to change `code = 1` to result in a "T" shaped arrow head, rather than an arrow going in the opposite direction.

I tried looking for packages that might change this but I had no luck and I couldn't seem to figure out how to edit the arrows function by myself, if anyone could give me some pointers that would be wonderful!

Comment: Can you provide a minimal code example of your problem?

Comment: What is T shaped arrow? Do you mean `arrows(..., angle = 90)`?

Comment: As in, the arrow point looks like a 'T' rather than a triangle. Like an arrow with a blunt end, or a flat line perpendicular to the main arrow line? Can ```angle = 90``` conditionally plot arrows with a flat point (or no point)?

Comment: Also, sorry I can't supply a minimal code example because the arrow() function is working like normal and the network plotting isn't relevant. The code is as written above, when I use arrows in my network I supply a column with either 0, 1, 2 or 3 which determines the arrow direction, however I want to change ```code = 1``` parameter in arrows() to result in a blunt ended arrow rather than a backwards arrow, which you get if you plot an igraph object or networkD3 graph. I want to know how to change this within arrows().

Comment: `networkD3` does not use `arrows()`

Comment: Oh. I was under the impression that "arrows = logical value that can be enabled", was from the R graphics package:
```forceNetwork(Links, Nodes, Source, Target, Value, NodeID, Nodesize, Group,
  height = NULL, width = NULL,
  colourScale = JS("d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);"), fontSize = 7,
  fontFamily = "serif", linkDistance = 50,
  radiusCalculation = JS(" Math.sqrt(d.nodesize)+6"), charge = -30,
  linkColour = "#666", opacity = 0.6, zoom = FALSE, legend = FALSE,
  arrows = FALSE, bounded = FALSE, opacityNoHover = 0,
  clickAction = NULL)```

Comment: Nope, `networkD3` arrows are generated on the JavaScript side.